# EF-core delete composite key entity

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, composite-primary-key, icomparable

Below I have extracted relevant parts of the code. The problem is when X() is called. I get the following exception:

```
An exception occurred in the database while saving changes.
System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array. ---> System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.
  at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
  at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object )
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.ModificationCommandComparer.Compare(ModificationCommand x, ModificationCommand y)
  at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.InsertionSort(T[] keys, Int32 lo, Int32 hi, IComparer`1 comparer)
  at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.IntrospectiveSort(T[] keys, Int32 left, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
  at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Sort(Int32 index, Int32 count, IComparer`1 comparer)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.<BatchCommands>d__6.MoveNext()
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(Tuple`2 parameters)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
```

And currently I think the problem is due to the key I used there. I have a unique store ID for each store and I have a unique item ID for each item in each store. The globally unique ID of an item can be obtained using StoreId + ItemId.

I'm completely unsure why any kind of Sort is being called on SaveChanges here. The issue is present even if the key is not composite and just ItemId.

I'd be very happy to get any clues.

Code snippets:

```
// This is the entity class.
public class Item
{
  [Required]
  [MaxLength(MaxIdLength)]
  public byte[] ItemId { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [MaxLength(MaxIdLength)]
  public byte[] StoreId { get; set; }
}

// This is how I setup its Key in context - as I can see in the migration file, the key is created as expected.
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasKey(i => new { i.ItemId, i.StoreId });
  modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasIndex(i => new { i.ItemId, i.StoreId }).IsUnique();
}

// This is the problem
public void X()
{
  using (UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
  {
    List<Item> items = unitOfWork.ItemRepository.Get().ToList();

    foreach (Item item in items)
      unitOfWork.ItemRepository.Delete(item);

    unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
  }
}

// This is how Delete is implemented in the generic repository (i.e. ItemRepository).
public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
{
  if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
    dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);

  dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
}
```

**UPDATE:** When I tried to add a simple int as the primary key to the existing class, the code started to work.

**UPDATE 2:** Issue exists even if the key is just ItemId. Probably there is a problem that it is not autogenerated type of key.

Comment: What is the data type for ItemId and StoreId in database ?

Comment: It is BLOB NOT NULL (and in migration file it is `table.Column<byte[]>(maxLength: 32, nullable: false)`) and I forgot to mention I'm using SQLite with this. And there is CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY ("ItemId", "StoreId")

Comment: EF (and .net generally) can't compare two byte[]. Only Object that implements IComparable or primitive value like int or byte,... can be compare
So try to make Item as IComparable or use another type as primary key

Comment: I'm agreee with Silvinus, why do you use guid or int or varchar for pk ?

Comment: I also agree with Silvinus, but I have failed to found out how to make the item to implement IComparable so that it works with EF. When I implemented IComparable on the Item class, it made absolutely no difference, so I guess this question is about how to make this working.

Comment: @wapac, I had the same problem while trying to update records with byte[] field as part of their primary key. Investigating the error showed that EF tries to compare the keys to figure out the exact command which should be executed against the DB, but this happens only when there are multiple records pending persistance. If there is just one - no comparison is attempted on the byte[] field. So that could be your workaround - just call SaveChanges() on every iteration of your loop. I know it's not ideal, but it was the best I could do in my situation.

Comment: @nanestev: tx, my workaround was that I've added integer primary key to the table and it works perfectly with it; not ideal either but works